# select one row based on a string

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a table like this:
[image]

and I want to have the output like this:

[image]

If I use case to this, I'm not getting a unique value for each pc. I used:

```
case
when software like '%7zip%' then software
else 'no'
end;
```

and I'm getting for computer_id something like this:
[image]

I don't know what function to use and if I can do this with 'case'.
Thank you!

Comment: *and I'm getting for computer_id something like this:* Now group by computer and take MIN(Software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish but I think you basically want only the `Computer_ids` of the rows that have `Sofrware` of `7Zip` or the `Computer_ids` of the rows that don't have `Software` of `7Zip` in any other row for that same `Computer_id`, and you want the value to be `no`. You can accomplish this with a `UNION ALL` clause and an **outer self-join** like so:

```
-- This gets you only the rows with 7Zip in the Software field
SELECT Computer_id, Software
FROM TableName
WHERE Software like '%7zip%'

UNION ALL

-- This gets you only the rows of Computer IDs who don't have Software containing 7Zip in any other row
SELECT T1.Computer_id, 'no' AS Software
FROM TableName T1
LEFT JOIN TableName T2
    ON T1.Computer_id = T2.Computer_id
    AND T2.Software like '%7zip%'
WHERE T1.Software NOT LIKE '%7Zip%' 
    AND T2.Computer_id IS NULL
```

If you have the same `Computer_id` more than once in either case and you only want one row for it, you can add the `DISTINCT` clause to your `SELECT` clause in each query of the `UNION ALL` above too.

Comment: Thanks again. Worked. Nice jobs! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example using a CTE with conditional aggregation.

```
WITH inventory_per_computer AS (
    SELECT Computer_id, SUM(CASE soft WHEN '7Zip' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Installed
    FROM dbo.SoftwareInventory
    GROUP BY Computer_id
    )
SELECT Computer_id, CASE Installed WHEN 0 THEN 'no' ELSE '7Zip' END AS Software
FROM inventory_per_computer
ORDER BY Computer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a reference table and use it to do a left join like so:

```
create table demo (computer_id int, soft varchar(20));
insert into demo values (1,'Adobe'),(1,'Office'),(2,'Adobe'),(2,'7Zip'),(3,'7Zip'),(1,'7Zip')
,(4,'7Zip'),(5,'office'),(6,'Adobe');

select * from demo;

with ref as (select distinct computer_id from demo)
select r.computer_id, ISNULL(d.soft, 'no')
from ref r
left join demo d on r.computer_id = d.computer_id and d.soft = '7Zip'

drop table demo;
```